# What is the best way of getting a part-time PhD in Europe?

Tags: phd, part-time

I am interested in pursuing a part-time PhD parallel to having a job in the industry.

In particular, I am a financial professional based in Germany and I am interested in a PhD in Economics orFinance.

Comment: see https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/131344/72855

Comment: Check out this program in France - http://www.anrt.asso.fr/sites/default/files/plaquette_cifre_en.pdf