# Is the German "individual doctorate" program available in Switzerland?

Tags: switzerland

In the question below is asked whether an 'individual doctorate' program is available in Germany (further specification in the link):

[What is the traditional way of earning a doctorate in Germany?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/131344/what-is-the-traditional-way-of-earning-a-doctorate-in-germany)

My question now is whether such type of doctorate is available in Switzerland or other European countries too?

Comment: The Swiss probably offer their own programmes and may not copy German ones even though they speak SwissGerman in the country. you will need to check the offerings of the institutions providing programs you are interested in.

Comment: I didn't mean they would copy just because they share a language. I just meant to ask whether in Switzerland or European countries such programs exist

Comment: As I clearly stated: you will need to check what is offered by the institutions for the subject / program that you ate interested in.